# TreeGrid. Как сделать на несколько строчек?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Установил компонент https://github.com/maxazan/jquery-treegrid

Он основан на table. Работает.

Но если я в одном td захочу сделать в несколько строчек c помощью br, то строчка сдвигается до конца влево. Как сделать, чтобы и 2-ая строчка выравнилась?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дайте ссылку на работающий пример. Или добавьте его с свой вопрос.

Comment: испортил временно свой сайт http://sitev.ru/ вверху Root node

Comment: удалось кое-что сделать, где "qqq aaa", как теперь стрелку вверх поднять? ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Составил код на основе [примера](http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/examples/example-bootstrap-resize.html).

Проблема в том, что стрелочки вниз и отступы сделаны инлайн-блоками 16 на 16 пикселей:

```
.treegrid-indent {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

У второй строки такого квадратика нет и она "проваливается" влево.

[image: проблема со вторым строками]

Можно решить, завернув содержимое первых ячеек в дополнительные инлайн-блоки. Заодно выровняем ячейки по верхней границе:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tree').treegrid();
});
```

```css
.tree td,
.treegrid-expander,
.treegrid-indent {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.tree td > div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/css/jquery.treegrid.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/js/jquery.treegrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/js/jquery.treegrid.bootstrap3.js"></script>

<table class="tree">
  <tr class="treegrid-1">
    <td><div>Root node<br>Second line</div></td><td>Additional info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1">
    <td><div>Node 1-1</div></td><td>Additional info<br>Second line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-1">
    <td><div>Node 1-2</div></td><td>Additional info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="treegrid-4 treegrid-parent-3">
    <td><div>Node 1-2-1<br>Second line</div></td><td>Additional info<br>Second line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```